# Does DOJO support Immutable Objects?

Tags: javascript, dojo, immutable.js, mori

I would like to know :

- if DOJO 1.10.1 supports Immutable objects.
- if DOJO 2.0 will support them.

If Immutable object are not supported, what libraries would you suggest to be included in DOJO 1.10.1?

I need to use this library using AMD and generally having a good workflow/integration with DOJO.

At the moment I am looking at the following libraries, but I have not previouse experience with DOJO usage, not sure which one could fit the best in a real world application.

https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

http://swannodette.github.io/mori/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an immutable object in JavaScript then call `Object.freeze(object)`. You don’t need a library for that.